# How to change view after hide SliverPersistentHeader

Tags: flutter, mobile, dart, appbar

I need AppBar that shows other view on up scrolling.
Is it possible?

Bellow is my attempts to realize it. But...

## This is what I need:

when scrolled down:

[image: This is what I need]

and when up scrolled

[image: collapsed]

## but I have now this:

Here is how I do this:

```
class DetailedEvent extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
               body: CustomScrollView(
                 slivers: <Widget>[
                   SliverPersistentHeader(
                     pinned: true,
                     floating: false,
                     delegate: _SliverAppBarDelegate(),//HERE IS CUSTOM HEADER CLASS
                   )
```

---

This class used in MainPage:

```
class _SliverAppBarDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {


double scrollAnimationValue(double shrinkOffset) {
    double maxScrollAllowed = maxExtent - minExtent;
    return ((maxScrollAllowed - shrinkOffset) / maxScrollAllowed)
        .clamp(0, 1)
        .toDouble();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(
    BuildContext context,
    double shrinkOffset,
    bool overlapsContent,
  ) {
    final tableTitleStyle =
        TextStyle(color: AppColors.appWhiteDarker, fontSize: 16);

    final tableValueStyle = TextStyle(color: AppColors.pureWhite, fontSize: 16);

    final double visibleMainHeight = max(maxExtent - shrinkOffset, minExtent);
    final double animationVal = scrollAnimationValue(shrinkOffset);
    return Container(
      height: visibleMainHeight,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: <Widget>[
          ...,
          Positioned(
            bottom: 0.0,
            child: SizedBox(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                children: <Widget>[...],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override...
}
```

[image: this is what I have now]

Comment: Hi, @Urma did you get your answer?

Comment: Hi @abbasjafary I created custom appbar, extended flutters SliverAppbar.

Comment: Can you share your code, please?